# How to performance tune high /wait/io/redo_log_flush values in "commit"

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-8.0, aws-aurora, amazon-rds-aurora

According to the "Top SQL" view in *AWS Performance Insights*, `commit` tops the list of SQL statements in terms of *average active session (AAS)*.

And most of the time seems to be spent in `wait/io/redo_log_flush`. I have read the [docs on io/aurora_redo_log_flush](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/ams-waits.io-auredologflush.html) - which I assume to be the name of wait/io/redo_log_flush prior to Aurora 3 - but they don't really help me, because there are apparently only 0.25 commits per second, but the load is close to 15 AAS. So it is not a problem of too many small commits.

So why would such a low commit rate lead to such a high AAS? How can I dig deeper into this?

N.B. We are using *8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.1*

[image]

Comment: Stare at your transactions.  Estimate the number of rows being modified (Updated/Deleted).  Ask yourself if there is a better way to design the data flow so not as many rows are being modified.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?  I'm experiencing it after upgrading from Aurora 2 to Aurora 3.  Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to share what we found that was causing this problem on our database.  We use fulltext indexes in our database, and our mysql error logs were full of an error saying "[ERROR] [MY-012298] [InnoDB] (Duplicate key) writing word node to FTS auxiliary index table. (fts0fts.cc:4219)".  We dropped and re-created our fulltext indexes and this error stopped and our COMMIT times went back to normal.  Another culprit for us was the use of the "upsert" syntax "INSERT (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE(...)".  Both of these things seem to cause thrashing in some of our write operations. Good luck!

Comment: @KOTJMF Could you possibly post your comment as an actual answer? Seems legitimate.  Comments sometimes get deleted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameter 'innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit' if it's set to 1, make it to 0. This gives better performance, but a server crash can erase the last second of transactions.

https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql-dbaas/ref/mdb/system-variables/innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit/